# Test Harness tool for COAP and MQTT

Tags: automated-tests, mqtt, coap

I am looking for some automated tool to test the basic functionality for CoAP and MQTT protocol. 
I have figured out the jMeter but it does not works for CoAP as it does not handle the UDP requests.

Please share if anybody know a tool that can be used to test CoAP and/or MQTT

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Paho project provides interoperability tests for MQTT. There is more information here:

http://eclipse.org/paho/clients/testing/